# Readlines.() repeats the same answer?

Tags: python

```
**Required Weather Program:**

The Weather
Create a program that:
imports and opens a file
appends additional data to a file
reads from the file to displays each city name and month average high temperature in Celsius
Output: The output should resemble the following

City of Beijing month ave: highest high is 30.9 Celsius
City of Cairo month ave: highest high is 34.7 Celsius
City of London month ave: highest high is 23.5 Celsius
City of Nairobi month ave: highest high is 26.3 Celsius
City of New York City month ave: highest high is 28.9 Celsius
City of Sydney month ave: highest high is 26.5 Celsius
City of Tokyo month ave: highest high is 30.8 Celsius
City of Rio De Janeiro month ave: highest high is 30.0 Celsius
all of the above text output is generated from the file
the only strings are hard coded:

"is"
"of"
"Celsius"
import the file into the Jupyter Notebook environment
use !curl to download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftLearning/intropython/master/world_temp_mean.csv as mean_temp.txt
# [ ] The Weather: import world_mean_team.csv as mean_temp.txt into the Jupyter notebook


Add the weather for Rio
Open the file in append plus mode ('a+')
Write a new line for Rio de Janeiro "Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0\n"
Grab the column headings
use .seek() to move the pointer to the beginning of the file
read the first line of text into a variable called: headings
convert headings to a list using .split(',') which splits on each comma
# [ ] The Weather: open file, read/print first line, convert line to list (splitting on comma)


Read the remaining lines from the file using a while loop
assign remaining lines to a city_temp variable
convert the city_temp to a list using .split(',') for each .readline() in the loop
print each city & the highest monthly average temperature
close mean_temps
Tips & Hints:

print headings to determine indexes to use for the final output (what is in headings[0], [1], [2]..?)
the city_temp data follows the order of the headings (city_temp[0] is described by headings[0])
The output should look like: "month ave: highest high" for Beijing is 30.9 Celsius
convert city_temp to lists with .split(',')
# [ ] The Weather: use while loop to print city and highest monthly average temp in celsius
```

My code:

```
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftLearning/intropython/master/world_temp_mean.csv -o mean_temp.txt

exam_file=open('mean_text.txt', 'a+')



exam_file.seek(0,0)
city_temp = exam_file.readline().split(",")
citystemp = exam_file.readline().split(",")
citytemp = exam_file.readline().split(",")
city_tem = exam_file.readline().split(",")
citystem = exam_file.readline().split(",")
citytem = exam_file.readline().split(",")
city_te = exam_file.readline().split(",")




print("City of", city_temp[0], "month ave: highest high is", city_temp[2], "Celsius")
print("City of", citystemp[0], "month ave: highest high is", citystemp[2], "Celsius")
print("City of", citytemp[0], "month ave: highest high is", citytemp[2], "Celsius")
print("City of", city_tem[0], "month ave: highest high is", city_tem[2], "Celsius")
print("City of", citystem[0], "month ave: highest high is", citystem[2], "Celsius")
print("City of", citytem[0], "month ave: highest high is", citytem[2], "Celsius")
print("City of", city_te[0], "month ave: highest high is", city_te[2], "Celsius")

exam_file.write("Rio de Janeiro, Brazil, 30.0, 18.0, \n")
cityste = exam_file.readline().split(",")
print("City of", cityste[0], "month ave: highest high is", cityste[2], "Celsius")


exam_file.seek(0)


exam_file.close()
exam_file = open("mean_text.txt","r")
exam = exam_file.read
print(exam)
```

My output:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   222  100   222    0     0    991      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1072
City of Rio de Janeiro month ave: highest high is 30.0 Celsius
City of Rio de Janeiro month ave: highest high is 30.0 Celsius
City of Rio de Janeiro month ave: highest high is 30.0 Celsius
City of Rio de Janeiro month ave: highest high is 30.0 Celsius
City of Rio de Janeiro month ave: highest high is 30.0 Celsius
City of Rio de Janeiro month ave: highest high is 30.0 Celsius
City of Rio de Janeiro month ave: highest high is 30.0 Celsius
City of Rio de Janeiro month ave: highest high is 30.0 Celsius
<built-in method read of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x7fdd00fad558>
```

Why does it show the same thing over and over again even though I appended Rio instead of replacing the other things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can read all lines from the file using

```
alllines = exam_file.readlines()
header = alllines.pop(0)
```

iterate through rest of the lines through loop

`for line in alllines`

It is not a clean approach to call `readline()` multiple times to read each line separately.

Answer (score 0):

Because all files are the same?

```
exam_file.readline().split(",")
```

And because you are always Reading the same info of equal lists?

```
print("City of", city_temp[0], "month ave: highest high is", city_temp[2], "Celsius")
```

That should be some like:

```
city_temp=["Rio de Janeiro", "something", "something", "30.0"]
```

So you are always picking that `city_temp[0]` that is Rio de Janeiro and `city_temp[2]` that is "30.0".

I really didn't understand your example.